# JavaScript Circle vanishes on Collision

Tags: javascript, graphics, 2d

Making a little 2D JavaScript physics simulation. Working on circle to circle collisions right now. The problem is whenever 2 circles collide one of them disappears and the other collides correctly. I think it may have something to do with how I'm updating and detecting the collisions.

Here's my function

```
function animate() {
  c.fillStyle = "#000000";
  c.fillRect(container.x, container.y, container.width, container.height);
  var newVx1 = 0;
  var newVy1 = 0;

  //loop through the circles array
  for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    //draw the circles
    c.fillStyle = "hsl(" + circles[i].color++ + ", 100%, 100%)";
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(circles[i].x, circles[i].y, circles[i].r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    c.fill();
//check circle on circle collisions 
for (var an = 0; an < circles.length; an++) {
  if (an != i) {
    var a = circles[i].x - circles[an].x;
    var b = circles[i].y - circles[an].y;
    if (Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b) < circles[i].r + circles[an].r) {
      var xHit =
        circles[i].x * circles[an].r + circles[an].x * circles[i].r;
      var yHit =
        circles[i].y * circles[an].r + circles[an].y * circles[i].r;

      newVx1 =
        (circles[i].vx * (circles[i].mass - circles[an].mass) +
          2 * circles[i].mass[an] * circles[i].vx) /
        (circles[i].mass + circles[an].mass);
      //var temp = 0
      newVy1 =
        (circles[i].vy * (circles[i].mass - circles[an].mass) +
          2 * circles[an].mass * circles[an].vy) /
        (circles[i].mass + circles[an].mass);

      var newVx2 =
        (circles[an].vx * (circles[an].mass - circles[i].mass) +
          2 * circles[i].mass * circles[i].vx) /
        (circles[i].mass + circles[an].mass);

      var newVy2 =
        (circles[an].vy * (circles[an].mass - circles[i].mass) +
          2 * circles[i].mass * circles[i].vy) /
        (circles[i].mass + circles[an].mass);

      circles[i].vx = newVx1;
      circles[an].vx = newVx2;
      circles[i].vy = newVy1;
      circles[an].vy =newVy2;

    }
  }
}



if (
  circles[i].x - circles[i].r + circles[i].vx < container.x ||
  circles[i].x + circles[i].r + circles[i].vx >
    container.x + container.width
) {
  circles[i].vx = circles[i].bounce * -circles[i].vx;
  //circles[i].vx = -circles[i].vx;
}

if (
  circles[i].y + circles[i].r + circles[i].vy >
    container.y + container.height ||
  circles[i].y - circles[i].r + circles[i].vy < container.y
) {
  circles[i].vy = circles[i].bounce * -circles[i].vy;
  // circles[i].vx = -circles[i].vx;
}

circles[i].x += circles[i].vx;
circles[i].y += circles[i].vy;

circles[i].vy += 0.06;
//wind factor
    //circles[i].vx += .0001*circles[i].r
  }





  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

Comment: pls put this in a codepen or jsfiddle so people can better debug :)

Comment: https://codepen.io/DrewPoche/pen/aGEXGM I think this link should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually in Canvas when something magically disappeared, it might be because the data you passed to canvas are no longer valid.

If you console.log the circles data to debug, you will see that both "x" and "vx" are now NaN.

Keep backtracing this error and you will find that the NaN originates from this line of code, which has a typo.

```
newVx1 =
(circles[i].vx * (circles[i].mass - circles[an].mass) +
  2 * circles[i].mass[an] * circles[i].vx) /
(circles[i].mass + circles[an].mass);
```

See the  cirles[i].mass[an]? That will result in an undefinied which then lead to a NaN.

Your collision is still acting weird but at least now it's not disappearing. [Example](https://codepen.io/asiankingofwhales/pen/xjYOvR?editors=0010)